# How to create a percentage tracker that doesn't slow down the program significantly

Tags: python

I have a question regarding percentage trackers. I have a percentage tracker for a generation tool, and the percentage tracker significantly slows it down. (5 secs vs 35 secs)

```
def wiiu():
    time.sleep(0.2)
    track = 100000
    os.remove("Codes.txt")
    file = open("Codes.txt","w")
    clear()
    print("3ds and Wii-U Friend Code Generator")
    print("")
    print("How many codes to generate: ")
    amt = int(input())
    print("Generating...")
    total = 0
    total1 = 0
    file = open("codes.txt","w") 
    while total < amt:
        pc = 200/(int(amt)+(int(total)))
        total1 + 1
        pc1 = pc + 100
        fcpt1 = str(randint(1000, 9999)) + "-" + str(randint(1000, 9999)) + "-" + str(randint(1000,9999))
        total = total+1
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Friend Code Generator - " + str(round(total*pc)) + "% completed")
        if total == track:
            print(str(total) + " generated.")
            track = track + 100000
        file.write(str(fcpt1)+"\n")
    clear()
    file.close()
    if total == 1:
        print("Completed! Generated "+ str(total) +" code!")
    else:
        print("Completed! Generated "+ str(total) +" codes!")
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Friend Code Generator - 2.0.4")
    a = input("Press enter to close! Thanks for using!")
    close()
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What specifically is your question? Are you asking for tips on how to optimize your code? Have you done any basic debugging/profiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without proper profiling I can only guess but probably `ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW` takes some time especially when running it every iteration. Maybe just doing it every `100th` time makes it faster?

```
while total < amt:
        pc = 200/(int(amt)+(int(total)))
        total1 + 1
        pc1 = pc + 100
        fcpt1 = str(randint(1000, 9999)) + "-" + str(randint(1000, 9999)) + "-" + str(randint(1000,9999))
        total = total+1

        # Use the modulo operator to let it run every 100th time
        if total % 100 == 0:
            ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Friend Code Generator - " + str(round(total*pc)) + "% completed")
        if total == track:
            print(str(total) + " generated.")
            track = track + 100000
        file.write(str(fcpt1)+"\n")
```